# Using Node.js to write MySQL One-to-Many relationship

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have tried doing this several ways, and maybe node.js is the wrong language to use for this purpose, but I thought it could be quickly done with it. I am taking a contacts table with names and addresses, and converting it to two tables with a one-to-many relationship, so that one contact can have multiple addresses. The desired data structure is like this:

Contact Table
contactId
firstName
lastName
phone
email
etc...

Address Table
addressId
contactId
street
city
state
etc...

Currently all fields are in the same table.

The result I am getting is that the data in the second query never changes. So if I write the contact query first, then it works as expected, but the addresses all end up as duplicates of one contact's address. If I insert the address record first, then I get duplicate records of one contact. I tried nesting the queries first, but I split them out when I got this behavior. My thinking was that I could write the queries . I need to write the contact and get the ID back, then write the address with the contactID. OR I need to write the address and get THAT ID back, and then write the contact, get that ID, and then do an update query to put the contactId into the address record. This last method is the attempt shown in the code below.

Here is my code currently:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM pfPeople";
connection.query(sql, function(err, result, fields)  {
    if (err) throw err;

    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        var names = result[i].fullName.replace(/"/g, "'").split(" ");

        var sql2 = "INSERT INTO contact (firstName, lastName, title, phone1, phone2, fax, email1, notes, org) VALUES (" + 
        "\"" + names[0] + "\", \"" + names[1] + "\", \"" + result[i].title.replace(/"/g, "'") + " \", \"" + result[i].phone1 + "\", \"" + 
        result[i].phone2 + "\", " + "\"" + result[i].phone3 + "\", \"" + result[i].email + "\", \"" + result[i].notes.replace(/"/g, "'") + "\", \"" + 
        result[i].org.replace(/"/g, "'") + "\")";

        var street = result[i].street;
        var city = result[i].city;
        var state = result[i].state;
        var zip = result[i].zip;
        var country = result[i].country;

        var sql3 = "INSERT INTO address (address1, city, state, zip, country) VALUES (" + 
        "\"" + street + "\", \" " + city + "\", \"" + state + "\", \"" + zip + "\", \"" + country + "\")";

        var contactId;
        var addressId;

        connection.query(sql2, function(err, cResult) {
            if (err) throw err;

            var contactId = cResult.insertId;

            console.log("Inserted ID: " + contactId);
        });

        connection.query(sql3, function(err, aResult) {
            if (err) throw err;

            var addressId = aResult.insertId;
        });

        var sql4 = "UPDATE address set contactId = " + contactId + " WHERE (addressId = " + addressId + ")";

        connection.query(sql4, function(err, uRes) {
            console.log("Address updated " + addressId + " " + contactId);
        });

        if (i > 3) break;
    }
});
```

Comment: This seems like it could be done in two `INSERT INTO <table> SELECT... ` statements instead of looping and all that.

Comment: I have about given up on node.js for this. I am noticing other weirdness in the data that I can attribute to the asynchronous nature of node.js.

Comment: Well... honestly I think this is more of a decision to push your logic to the database instead of trying to handle on your server or client side. Anytime you find yourself looping through a result set from a query and then kicking off other queries inside that loop you can generally refactor by getting rid of the loop and combining your queries. In this case like `INSERT INTO contact SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 1) as firstname, SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', -1) as lastname, title, ... FROM pfPeople;` Let MySQL do alll the heavy lifting here.

Comment: I started doing that, but I need the insertID from adding the contact to create the address record. I know about last_insert)_id, but I couldn't figure out how to use that to insert into the address table in between inserts to the contacts table without using some sort of script. Which led me to node.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well i add some promises to make it easier. the problem was you didnt wait for the responses to finish. try this code

```js
var sql = "SELECT * FROM pfPeople";
connection.query(sql, function(err, result, fields)  {
    if (err) throw err;

    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        var names = result[i].fullName.replace(/"/g, "'").split(" ");

        var sql2 = "INSERT INTO contact (firstName, lastName, title, phone1, phone2, fax, email1, notes, org) VALUES (" + 
        "\"" + names[0] + "\", \"" + names[1] + "\", \"" + result[i].title.replace(/"/g, "'") + " \", \"" + result[i].phone1 + "\", \"" + 
        result[i].phone2 + "\", " + "\"" + result[i].phone3 + "\", \"" + result[i].email + "\", \"" + result[i].notes.replace(/"/g, "'") + "\", \"" + 
        result[i].org.replace(/"/g, "'") + "\")";

        var street = result[i].street;
        var city = result[i].city;
        var state = result[i].state;
        var zip = result[i].zip;
        var country = result[i].country;

        var sql3 = "INSERT INTO address (address1, city, state, zip, country) VALUES (" + 
        "\"" + street + "\", \" " + city + "\", \"" + state + "\", \"" + zip + "\", \"" + country + "\")";

        const contacPromise = new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
           connection.query(sql2, function(err, cResult) {
              if (err) return reject( err);
              resolve( cResult.insertId);
          });
        })
       
        const addressPromise = new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
            connection.query(sql3, function(err, aResult) {
                if (err) return reject( err);
                resolve(aResult.insertId);
            });
        })
        Pomise.all([contacPromise,addressPromise])
        .then(([contactId,addressId]) =>{
           var sql4 = "UPDATE address set contactId = " + contactId + " WHERE (addressId = " + addressId + ")";

          connection.query(sql4, function(err, uRes) {
              console.log("Address updated " + addressId + " " + contactId);
          });
        
        })
        .catch(err => throw err)



        if (i > 3) break;
    }
});
```

Comment: You're right! This is much better. The last query is not working, but the others are much better. This is definitely a big step in the right direction. I guess I need to study up on my promises. I think I can switch them back around so I'm doing the address insert last, and use the contactId from the promise? I'll try that next. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: I got this working with some tweaks to your code. The throw inside the catch was apparently a problem, I turned this into an old-style callback with a console.log, and that made it happy. I'm going to accept your answer. Thanks again for the help!